# Issue when setting the value of a FloatRangeSlider in IPywidgets (float not exact, changing to old values...)

Tags: python, widget, slider, ipython, ipywidgets

Using IPywidgets, I am trying to set a value to a FloatRangeSlider. I only have one line of code setting it (apart from the definition) that runs when I click a button called `A` : `slider_skope1.value = [round(le_min[0],1), round(le_top[0],1)]`, `le_min` and `le_top` being set right before that.

It happens that the value I get is not the one I ask : often slightly different, sometimes not this at all.

To debug it, I wrote :

```
def temp_debug(b):
        print("debug", b)
slider_skope1.observe(temp_debug)
```

And a click on `A` gives me : (abbreviated, we don't need the full definition of FloatRangeSlider)

```
debug {'name': 'description', 'old': 'Test:', 'new': 'AveRooms', 'owner': FloatRangeSlider...}

debug {'name': 'max', 'old': 100000000000.0, 'new': 59.9, 'owner': FloatRangeSlider...}

debug {'name': 'min', 'old': -100000000000.0, 'new': 1.6, 'owner': FloatRangeSlider...}

debug {'name': 'value', 'old': (5.0, 7.5), 'new': (1.6, 11.1), 'owner': FloatRangeSlider...}

debug {'name': '_property_lock', 'old': {}, 'new': {'value': [5, 7.500000000000002]}, 'owner': FloatRangeSlider...}

debug {'name': 'value', 'old': (1.6, 11.1), 'new': (5.0, 7.500000000000002), 'owner': FloatRangeSlider...}

debug {'name': '_property_lock', 'old': {'value': [5, 7.500000000000002]}, 'new': {}, 'owner': FloatRangeSlider...}

debug {'name': '_property_lock', 'old': {}, 'new': {'value': [1.6, 11.1]}, 'owner': FloatRangeSlider...}

debug {'name': 'value', 'old': (5.0, 7.500000000000002), 'new': (1.6, 11.1), 'owner': FloatRangeSlider...}

debug {'name': '_property_lock', 'old': {'value': [1.6, 11.1]}, 'new': {}, 'owner': FloatRangeSlider...}
```

I really don't understand why the value is changing veeeery slightly (like +0.00...002), why it comes back to its past one etc. Is it somewhat linked to the approximations python does with float values ?

I also don't quite understand what is property lock, and I can"t find documentation about it...

My full code is 2000 lines+ with a lot of variables, so I hope that I can get some help only providing this.

The value changes even after that the fonction called when I click on `A` is finished !

Thanks in advance for your help , let me know if you need more information about my code in order to help me do some progress.

Note : I also have `slider_skope1.observe(on_value_change_skope1, names="value")` which changes the values displayed on an histogram - it should not be an issue in my case but maybe it is.

```
def on_value_change_skope1(b1):
        with fig_skope1.batch_update():
            new_list = [g for g in list(X_base[nom_colonnes[0]].values) if g >= slider_skope1.value[0] and g <= slider_skope1.value[1]]
            if len(fig_skope1.data) == 1:
                fig_skope1.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=new_list, bingroup=1, nbinsx=nombre_bins, marker_color='blue'))
            else :
                fig_skope1.data[1].x = new_list
```